# How to specify a listening port for OpenLDAP in slapd.conf

Tags: linux, ssl, openldap

Though I know we can specify another port number when lauching OpenLDAP in commandline , I would like to set it up in `slapd.conf` so that `service slapd start` will make life easier.

Comment: 1. Off topic. 2. Unless you can find such an option in *man slapd.conf,* which I can't, there isn't one.

Answer (score 7):

Atleast in ubuntu, debian etc, you can specify this behavior in this file:

```
/etc/default/slapd
```

To specify slapd to use ssl(deprecated, I know), and use a custom port, I use:

```
SLAPD_SERVICES="ldap:/// ldapi:/// ldaps://my-url.com:1636/"
```

So, the list of ports,urls is space-separated. Note that you need three slashes

Answer (score 0):

The port slapd should listen on is set through binary startup arguments, with an ldap uri, your answer is in man (8) slapd , not in slapd.conf manpage.

http://linux.die.net/man/8/slapd

Comment: and the question should go to superuser.com . Moreover, you don't seem to try anything, starting with websearch e.g. "how do I set port slapd should listen on"